# Google Script Editor - script to continuously monitor column

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Thanks in advance for your help, i've been working on this for a long time with no tangible results.

I'm using TypeForm (https://www.typeform.com/) to receive answers to a questionnaire.  I'm then using Zapier (zapier.com) to input the responses as a row in a google sheets doc when the form is submitted.

The issue is that there are a few empty columns that i need to fill in once the data is submitted. For example, customer number,as well as Order Date.

I can't get anything to work because the OnEdit function only works for manual edits. I was also thinking about using OnOpen but could get it to work.

What i'm hoping for is a script that runs continuously to check and see if the cells within the column have data in them, and if so, on same row but different column enter in the date (MM dd YYYY) and then in another cell in the same row would be the customer id. The customer id would be generated by sequentially adding a number to that days date. For example. if it was todays date, the customer id would be 063020170001 (there were be 3 extra digits of padding). The next form that came in for the same day would have 063020170002 as a customer Id. Then, the next day, when a form comes in, the customer id would change with day and the sequence would start over, 070120170001. Lastly, once a date has been inputted into a cell, i don't want to allow it be written over, basically don't have the script look at that cell once it's written to.

If you have any advice on how to create this script or even what direction to take, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Check  out [timebased triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).  They work very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example as a starting point for you.You'll probably have different data so you'll have to change some of the column indexes, Spreadsheet ID and sheetnames. You will also have to hook this up to a time based trigger which you can do from the Script Editor in Edit/Current Project Triggers.

```
function checkFormResponses()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SSID');//add spreadsheet id
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('SHEETNAME');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var rgA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<rgA.length;i++)
  {
    if(!rgA[i][4])//COLUMN INDEXES WILL PROBABLY NEED CHANGING
    {
      rgA[i][4]=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-6', 'd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
      rgA[i][5]=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-6', "MMddyyyy") + paddingLeft(String(i),"0",4);

    }
   }
   rg.setValues(rgA);
}

function paddingLeft(padded,padding,length)
{
  var s=padded;
  for(var i=0;s.length<length;i++)
  {
    s= padding + s;
  }
  return s;
}
```

My Spreadsheet looks like this.

[image]

And after being filled in:

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly. Is there a way to also add a static value, actually two separate static values (shipping account and customer ID) to two separate columns? So for every order, additionally, the same customer ID and shipping account would be generated. Thanks again, i was just expected guidance, but you're amazing for writing the script!

Comment: Never mind, i figured it out. Thanks again @Cooper you rock!

Comment: Is there any way to make it so that when the day changes, the Order # goes back to 1, so for example on July 1st there were 100 orders so the order numbers would look like 070120170001-010120170100, but for july 2nd, can you make the counter go back to 1. 070220170001?
Thanks again for all you help! You're amazing!